# Varistor - Place before or after the fuse?

Tags: fuses, circuit-protection, surge-protection, over-voltage-protection, varistor

What is safer? Before or after the fuse?
In my case the varistor is 10mm, 275Vrms, and it is currently placed after a 250Vac, 7A, 20mm glass fuse. Would the varistor blow the fuse easily if placed after? I will not say if the fuse is fast or slow action type, you should consider that in practice the fuse will be one of those are selled in any little electronics store, a standard/commom fuse... I don't know if those commom fuses that you find in any electronics store are slow or fast action type...
But anyway, there was a day that I asked myself if there would be any advantage of puting the varistor before the fuse, directly in parallel with the mains, I don't have an answer for that yet.

Regards

Comment: Look at the end of the fuse, where the rating is stamped.  If it has a "T", then it is slow.  If it has "F", it is fast.  So "F7A 250V" would be a fast fuse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fuse should come first.

Varistor is meant to be conducting/protecting **for short timed events**. Fuse should act first and is also cheaper.

Comment: Also varistors tend to fail short-circuited so they need fuse protection themselves.

Comment: Do you know if the commom fuses selled on those electronics stores are generally slow or fast blow type? I think in this case it would be better to be slow blow type...

Comment: With this topic, I wanted to have sure that it is better to place the varistor after the fuse. Just wanted to confirm that. Answered!

Answer (score 1):

For over voltage protection circuit

Fuse first  then varistor  , varistor helps fuse to cut so the circuit opens .

For choosing fuse  :

this will help you

https://www.powerelectronics.com/technologies/passive-components/article/21863300/selecting-fuses-simple-procedures-to-get-the-right-overcurrent-protection-for-dcdc-converters